# Repetitive error handling in all functions inside a class

Tags: python

what's the best practice in handling errors inside a class that's responsible for API communication?

Here's what the class looks like:

```
class apiHandler():
    def __init__():
        self.payload = ....
        self.headers = ....

    def funcONE(self):
        url = "https://something/api/v1/something_ONE"
        try:
            r = requests.requests("POST",url,data=...,header...)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e_http:
            print(e_http)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e_oth:
            print(e_oth)

    def funcTWO(self):
        url = "https://something/api/v1/something_TWO"
        try:
            r = requests.requests("POST",url,data=...,header...)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e_http:
            print(e_http)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e_oth:
            print(e_oth)

    def funcTHREE(self):
        url = "https://something/api/v1/something_THREE"
        try:
            r = requests.requests("PUT",url,data=...,header...)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e_http:
            print(e_http)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e_oth:
            print(e_oth)
```

As you all can see, the three functions are pretty "fat" due to the same exceptions pattern. There's a lot of repetition between the three of them. Do you guys think this is considered normal or there's a better way to write this? I'm just trying to step up my Python game. Thanks.

Comment: I would think it's best practice to use try blocks and I don't know of any central error catching mechanism in use in python...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can factor the common parts of those three functions into one.  They only differ in the arguments to `requests.requests`, so you would make those arguments to the common function.

Something like this:

```
    def funcGeneral(self, url, method):
        try:
            r = requests.request(method, url, data=...,header...)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e_http:
            print(e_http)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e_oth:
            print(e_oth)
```

Then, for example, the definition of `funcONE` could reduce to `funcGeneral("https://something/api/v1/something_ONE", "POST")`.

You didn't show the data or header arguments, so I don't know whether they are the same for all such functions.  If they're not, you can make them parameters just like `url` and `method`.

If you take this approach, you lose some information when an exception is thrown, because instead of the exception coming out of funcONE, funcTWO, or funcTHREE, it will always be coming from funcGeneral.  If you consider this effect undesirable, you can remedy it by adding some lines in the exception-reporting blocks to report on the parameters to the function.

(By the way, the `requests` library doesn't seem to have a `requests` function.  I assume you meant the `request` function.)

Comment: I didn't think about this, but this makes sense as the only difference from each function is just the URL. Also, yes, I made a typo. It's supposed to be 'request' not 'requests'